# Xamarin forms App() gets called twice on startup

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have a problem with my Xamarin Forms application. Every time i start the android solution, App() constructor gets called twice. I fixed this by making the app entrypoint a singleton.

But every view constructor also gets called twice, and i cant figure out why?

Is this a bug?

I should mention, that i have written all views in code behind - and if its relevant somehow - im using the genymotion emulator.

Code in App nothing fancy:

```
bool isInitialized = false;
    public App()
    {
        if (!isInitialized)
        {
            isInitialized = true;

        navigationPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginView());
        MainPage = NavigationPage;
        Observer = new NetworkObserver();
        Debug.WriteLine("Observer initialized");
       }
    }
```

Code in android solution - i havent changed anything here:

```
    [Activity(Label = "XamarinClients", Icon = "@drawable/icon", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
        public class MainActivity : 

global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }

    }
```

After testing IOS application, i can see i have the same problem, it also calls App() twice - and also the pages constructors.

[image: First step in]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show us some code of your initialization (where you call Forms.Init()).

Comment: Couldn't find Forms.Init().. did you mean App()?

Comment: Try to put a breakpoint inside your App() constructor and check the call stack from the debugger, during the first and the second breakpoint hits. Post the call stack here, so we'll be able to help more.

Comment: Ok added the callstack. If you need more please let me know

Comment: Oh forgot to mention. This is a new project, that reproduces the problem. I have added no code beside from a page - that gets set as mainpage in app ctor

Comment: You say that you get to the constructor twice. I suspect that the call stack is not the same first and second time. I asked you to post them both, because I wanted to compare them. Can you please post the call stack in both cases? Also, before posting, right-click on the call stack and check "show external code"  checkbox. I think  this will give us a clue...

Comment: Ok i added some more screenshots. External code was ticked - so i hope this may provide you with useful info.

Comment: Sorry, but probably I miss something. You've added screenshots, but they are all from different lines in your program. You say that your application enters the constructor of App(), then executes some other code and then enters it again. Try to put just one breakpoint, in the beginning of App() constructor, and make a screenshot of the stack. Then continue  execution, wait for the second entrance to the constructor and make a screenshot of the stack again. Do you see the difference between these screenshots? Are they exactly the same? There MUST be a difference - application has just one flow!

Comment: 1, 4 and 5 are from the same line. 2 and 3 shows the line where binding context gets set - and it gets called twice in a row.

Comment: .. every line gets called twice in a row. Im sorry but dont know how else to put it.. Every event gets subscribed to twice, and so does every variable. Its like two threads are running parallel of eachother.

Comment: OK, this at least makes SOME sense... It really looks looks like 2 executions in parallel. So let's see where does it split. The application starts in Main method of Application class. Do you get there twice as well?  (put breakpoint in your Main.cs file to check this). Then it goes to AppDelegate.cs. Do you get twice to its FinishedLaunching method? It is something really simple - probably you duplicated some line of code. We just need to know where it is. Also, open Debug->windows->threads and check thread id each time your breakpoint is hit. Generally, it should be #1 only...

Comment: @OneBigQuestion did you get the answer/solution. I am facing the same problem my Content Page `OnAppearing()` method is calling twice only in `Android` but it is calling once in `iOS`

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same issue.  App() is launched twice from Xamarin Forms.  I hope this is fixed in a newer Xamarin Forms release.  This issue for me started with the Xamarin Forms version that released between 3/2017 and 6/2017.  Older versions did not do this Xamarin Forms version released in 5/2016 - 7/2016 worked perfectly.  No code change happened.

Comment: I did. The issue was in Remove Page from the navigation stack. It killed the navigation and made it jump back to the start of the application.  I also found any error in navigation kicks the app back to the main navigation page each time.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, which was causing lots of problems since it would end up hitting my API server twice. Ultimately I found this source: https://www.xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-async-task-startup/ , which states to put async Task in the OnStart method (and make the OnStart async, obviously). Once I moved the function down to the OnStart methods, my double call problems went away,.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else makes the same dumb mistake that I just made, check to ensure that you are not debugging on two different platforms at the same time.

I set my solution to have multiple startup projects, so I was deploying to both iOS and Android. I was only paying attention to my Android device, so I didn't even notice the app launching on the iPhone beside me.

This explains why my App constructor was getting called twice.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have added <Content.BindingContext> on the View Model? If yes try to remove it. I also facing this problem and I found that remove <Context.Binding> able to solve this problem.